# Opciones para desarrollar aplicación para IOS con xamarin sin Mac

Tags: ios, xamarin

Sé que es media archiconocida la pregunta, pero qué métodos conocen con el que se puedan desarrollar aplicaciones basadas en xamarin? Cuento con iPhone, lo único (y principal) no tengo Mac xD.

Comment: utiliza virtual box e instlate la IO de Mac

Answer (score 2):

Las opciones que tenes son:

**1. Xamarin Studio**

En vez de usar visual studio, puedes correr xamarin studio sobre una maquina virtual (por ejemplo VMWare) instalando una imagen MAC OS X. Ademas, las herramientas que necesitas son mono, xamarin studio, monotouch y xcode.

**2. Mac in cloud**

Si deseas utilizar visual studio, podes rentar una mac en la nube a través de [MacInCloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) y configurarla en visual studio.

**3. Xamarin Live Player**

Desde Mayo de 2017 es posible desarrollar iOS sin MAC. Microsoft incluyó [xamarin live player](https://www.xamarin.com/live) en visual studio donde es posible deployar una aplicación iOS en un dispositivo iOS desde visual studio.

Saludos